# updating summary sheet with values from multiple sheets in difference cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am quite new to VBA, I have attempted to write a code below, but I'm getting a type mismatch error (Highlighted below). What I am trying to achieve is the following:

I have a list of properties on column A (all hyperlinked to their own respective sheets) on the first summary sheet called "sheet"

1. For each property, go to that properties sheet
2. Copy the value 3 cell right to the cell with the string "Total for this Property"
3. Switch back to "sheet" and paste the value into column D, next to the corresponding property name in column A.

I think the issue is the way I am referencing the value in the other sheet, but I can't seem to find anywhere how to reference a value that is located somewhere relative to a cell with a specific text.

Thank you in advanced!

```
Sub Summary()

    Dim MasterBook As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng, Rng2 As Range

    Set MasterBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set Sht = MasterBook.Worksheets("Sheet")
    Set Rng = Sht.Range("A6:A" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    Dim Cell As Range

    For Each Cell In Rng
    Cell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
    Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Cell.Value("Total for this Property").Offset(0, 3).Value  '<---- This line is giving the error

    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Your point 2 isn't clear to me, and your syntax on that line is wrong. Can you elaborate as to your expected results?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. What I meant is: For example: if cell A6 is called "123 Dan street" then open the sheet 123 Dan street and look for the cell with the text "Total for this property". in this example "Total for this property" text is located in cell A1920. So I want to copy the value, 3 cells right to it, so D1920 and then switch back to the summary sheet. and in column D paste the value (same row as "123 Dan street", so D6). I hope its clearer.

Comment: Yes I think that's clearer. I have posted a suggested solution so let me know how you get on. You were missing the bit to tell Excel to look for the text.

Comment: @kira123 you should accept SJR answer, since it's the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're after this:

```
Sub Summary()
    Dim Cell As Range, foundCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet")
        For Each Cell In .Range("A6", .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp))
            Cell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
            Set foundCell = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(what:="Total for this Property", lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 3).Value  '<---- This line is giving the error
        Next Cell
        .Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Small point but don't see any need for going to each sheet and then re-activating first sheet?

Comment: @SJR it's a "general" code in that it doesn't require cell content to be the _exact_ hyperlinked sheet name and just follows the hyperlink

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Sub Summary()

Dim MasterBook As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range

Set MasterBook = ThisWorkbook
Set Sht = MasterBook.Worksheets("Sheet")
Set Rng = Sht.Range("A6:A" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Rng
    Set Rng3 = MasterBook.Sheets(Cell.Text).Cells.Find(What:="Total for this Property", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not Rng3 Is Nothing Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Rng3.Offset(, 3).Value
    Else
        MsgBox "not found"
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: nice typing, beat me by a few seconds :)

Comment: @ShaiRado - thanks. Find is one of the few things I can do without having to double check all the syntax.

Comment: `Set Rng3 = Nothing` isn't necessary since `Rng3` is always set to some valid range reference or to `Nothing` by `Set Rng3 = MasterBook.Sheets...`

Comment: also add `LookIn:=xlValues` between `Find()` arguments and be sure it isn't looking in Formulas

Comment: Thank you, I have made that change as well.

Answer (score 3):

It's no wonder that this line is giving you trouble:

```
Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Cell.Value("Total for this Property").Offset(0, 3).Value
```

The `Value` property doesn't take arguments like this! I assume you are trying the find the cell with the text `Total for this Property` and offset 3 from it?

In that case you should look into the `Find` command.

```
Dim myFoundCell as Range
Set myFoundCell = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(what:="Total for this Property", lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not myFoundCell Is Nothing Then
    Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = myFoundCell.Offset(0,3).Value
End If
```

I think you'll also have trouble handling which workbook you're in (the `ActiveWorkbook`) after following a load of hyperlinks, so look into `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook`. What I mean is, that each range must be within a sheet on a given workbook. You're trying to copy across workbooks so will have to specify where data is going to / coming from.

Docs for `Find`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Another question when you get stuck perhaps.

Comment: you are missing the `Worksheet.Name` , so your  `myFoundCell` will get the first successful `Find`, by the `Worksheet.Index`, not necessary the right one

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook` is a reference to a `Workbook` object, hence it doesn't support `Find()` method. `ActiveSheet` would be the appropriate object

Comment: Thanks code corrected to include worksheet object, typo on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to "fetch" the value from a certail `Worksheet` (which name is placed in the cell) and not in the entire `Workbook`, you need to use the `Find` for that specific `Worksheet`.

The `Find` method syntax for that is :

```
Set FindRng = Worksheets(Cell.Value).Cells.Find("Total for this property")
```

**Sub-loop Code**:

```
Dim Cell As Range, FindRng As Range

For Each Cell In Rng
    Cell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True

    Set FindRng = Worksheets(Cell.Value).Cells.Find("Total for this property")

    If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then    ' verify that Find was successful
        Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = FindRng.Offset(0, 3).Value          
    End If
Next Cell
```

Comment: if it's to be assumed that cell value _is exactly_ the sheet name referenced in the hyperlink than you can avoid `Cell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True` statement.

Comment: @user3598756 as I recall from the PO previous posts, it is :)

Comment: then you can delete `Cell.Hyperlinks(1)...` statement